# JSON.parse() causes Error without any data

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am writing an `AWS Lambda Function`.

and I would request the API without `event.body` for test

```
export const check = async (event) => {
  try{
    console.log("it does work");
    const {email, uid} = JSON.parse(event.body); // email and uid both would be undefined..
    //JSON.parse() throw some Error, so the below codes doesn't work.
    //Also, I can't see any single word from the response.
    if(!email && !uid) throw "No body data!"; // I expected throw this string but it didn't happend
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({msg: "SUCCESS"})
    }
  }catch(e){
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({e: e})
    }
  }
}
```

I could get this response.

```
{
  e: {}
}
```

I want to see

```
{
  e: "Some sentences about Error caused by JSON.parse() or No body data!"  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the error message I believe you have to do it like this:

```
return {
  statusCode: 500,
  body: JSON.stringify({e: e.message})
}
```

Or, you can use `Error.prototype.toString()`.

```
return {
  statusCode: 500,
  body: JSON.stringify({e: e.toString()})
}
```

Remember, `e.message` would be undefined for your the manually throw error (`throw "No body data!";`). In that case, you can check if `e` is a `string`. If `string` the use `e` otherwise `e.message`.

Comment: Could I block to pass the error from `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: You mean, you want to continue even if `JSON.parse()` throws an error?

Comment: Yes! I want to throw the error using my if-statements

Comment: @zynkn, the use another (nested) try-catch to handle only the `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  }catch(e){
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({e: String(e)})
    }
  }
```

This will leave `e` as-is if it is already a string or convert it to a string containing the message if it is an `Error` object.